# I can't load images from Graph Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

url:  https://graph.facebook.com/100779423975829/picture?type=large;

other url with type normal: https://graph.facebook.com/100779423975829/picture?type=normal

---

I tried to load url with Glide, Picasso, UniversalImageLoader and decodeStream from BitmapFactory and don't have any good result and the result is the next:

- UniversalImageLoader: *Image can't be decoded*
- BitmapFactory: *bitmap = null*

If I open the url with Chrome pc I will automatically download the photo without opening it.

in the webview from my app, i check the redirects from this url:

1. https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=100779423975829&height=200&width=200
2. https://m.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=100779423975829&height=200&width=200

Anyone else is having problems loading image profiles from Facebook graphs?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The bug is resolved from Facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261587761048160/

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/q/49516674/7542765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this was a facebook bug. So the problem is fixed by themselves.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261587761048160/

Comment: Is this really fixed? I still get the download instead of the picture itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the redirections from http:// to https:// protocols hinders the downloading using Picasso,Glide ets. You may go ahead with following two approaches:

1. SimpleDraweeView from Facebook Sdk. It handles the redirection internally.
2. Make a graph request to fetch the re-directed url like below and use that url in picasso.

   new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                   "/"+fbUserId+"/picture?width="+width+"&height="+height+"&redirect=false",
                   null,
                   HttpMethod.GET,
                   new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                       public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

   ```
                       try {
                           String url = response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                           loadFacebookProfilePicInImageView(url);
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                   }
               }
       ).executeAsync();
   ```

Comment: Making a graph request for loading a public profile image is not convenient in case he wants to make several profile loadings

Comment: I use it for making many requests in my recycler view. It runs smoothly and in background. Otherwise, SimpleDraweeView can be used

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. If you don't want to use the graph api for loading the public profile picture (as in my case) we both have a problem unless someone knows the solution.

Comment: After researching a bit I got that the response headers of GET https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=100779423975829&height=200&width=200 contains 

Content-Disposition => attachment

And seems not being supported by Picasso,Glide, etc

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems to be a bug. I think we are best of just waiting a day or two instead of putting the effort in fixing this ourselves. See also : [Facebook graph user picture won't show on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513735/facebook-graph-user-picture-wont-show-on-mobile-devices) and https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/560392384345729/