# Facebook graph user picture won't show on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the url `https://graph.facebook.com/{app_user_id}/picture?width=120&height=120` to show the user picture on my app, but since this morning, it has stopped working on mobile devices.

Now, the same url redirects to `https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid={app_user_id}&height=120&width=120`. This url works on desktop web, but on mobile it redirects again to `https://m.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid={app_user_id}&height=120&width=120` and the mobile web refuses to output the image. If I try to load it in the address bar, it is downloaded instead of showed.

I have searched for any change on the Facebook graph api about this but didn't find anything. Any hint to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You are not alone, look like they have or currently are broking something https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/560392384345729/

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/q/49516674/7542765

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan that code is for an Android app, and it is a bit risky to state that the previous solution _won't work anymore_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. Started happening to my app earlier on this morning. Still no fix as of yet.

A few bug reports that have been submitted on Facebook for Developers:

1. [Profile Pictures Can't Load](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/179644422685765/)
2. [Graph API Profile picture doesn`t work on mobile](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261587761048160/)
3. [Cross site policy error while accessing graph pictures](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/235774226969068/)

Comment: Thanks, hope they fix it. Maybe it is related to the Cambridge Analytica scandal.

Comment: They have acknowledged the problem and have affected it to their team, see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261587761048160/

Comment: Wow, spent hours searching and "fixing" my site only to finally find this. I wish FB could find a way to send us a notification when stuff like this happens. I mean a profile picture issue on mobile is pretty big deal.

Comment: Issue is now fixed / pay attention to the new https://lookaside.facebook.com domain in case you have CSP policies

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue today and I'v found a solution for that and it worked for me.

After login we get below Profile pic URL

```
http://graph.facebook.com/11111111111/picture?type=large&height=320&width=420
```

> 11111111111 is your social id/facebook id

now we need to change this URL in order to display image,
here is the code.

```
try {
     profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
     Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic + "");
     Picasso.with(getContext()).
     load(profile_pic.toString())
     .placeholder(R.drawable.img)
     .into(imageviewId);
     }
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> **id is your socialid/facebook id**

in short we just need to remove **&height=320&width=420** from url.

> you can compare both the url:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/11111111111/picture?type=large&height=320&width=420

https://graph.facebook.com/11111111111/picture?type=large
```

**and yes you need to change http to https** as well

Answer (score 4):

Though I didn't find any official announcements, Facebook during last few days changed their api's, now when you request user's public profile the picture url has extra parameters, **ext** and **hash**

Calling the url without these params returns 404 error.

Not sure if the change is affecting Page Scope ID's only.

Currently, when you request user's public profile data the url looks like this
https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?psid=PAGE_SCOPED_ID&height=1024&ext=1522585606&hash=AeThc8c7EQDFgShs

before it was just

https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?psid=PAGE_SCOPED_ID&height=1024

It seems to me the only known solution currently would be requesting new public profile data and updating your database.

Hope that helps.