# Promlem with retrieving Facebook profile image

Tags: image, facebook, url, profile

From today I cant load Facebook profile picture with url
http://graph.facebook.com/profile_id/picture?type=large&width=200&height=200

Now it download small picture 8x8 pixel with question sign.

Not working for Android and Unity Editor.
On iOS devices works fine.

Any ideas how to get profile image?

Thanks.

Comment: When I try to download it through browser it works fine, but in the android application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook graph user picture won't show on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513735/facebook-graph-user-picture-wont-show-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Seems to be a bug. See also : [Facebook graph user picture won't show on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513735/facebook-graph-user-picture-wont-show-on-mobile-devices) and https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/560392384345729/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I use profile url that I get from Firebase, my solution as use profile url from facebook as below:

```
string imageUri = String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=large&width=100&height=100", your_id);

IEnumerator LoadImage(string imageUri)
    {

        WWW www = new WWW(imageUri);
        yield return www;

        Debug.Log("Width = " + www.texture.width + "; Height = " + www.texture.height);
        Avata.sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));
    }
```

And it work as well. Hope this help.