# user profile picture not showing in graph api call for recent api changes

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am displaying profile feed posts in website using graph api. graph api call is look like this -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=id,from,message,story,picture,link,source...&access_token=token here
```

so getting data by above call, i display posts by html codes in my site. 
I display profile picture by this html code -
`<img class="msfb-wall-avatar" src="https://graph.facebook.com/app_scoped_profile_id/picture?type=square">`

here app_scoped_profile_id i got from graph api call is different from normal profile id and is specific to the facebook application as i used that application's user token in above graph api call.

But now profile picture is not being shown, before there were no problems, so look like there were some changes in FB graph api. If i manually load above img src url in browser then i see some browser errors.So look like graph api not taking that app scoped user id to display profile pic.

So what i to do to display profile picture when displaying user profile feed posts according to any latest changes from facebook Graph Api?

Comment: Hello Fb developers?

Answer (score 1):

I am also experiencing this problem at the moment. Some time ago I was experiencing it as well. At that time it was reported to be a bug. I think it might be a bug again this time.

See the following links for more info:  [Facebook graph user picture won't show on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513735/facebook-graph-user-picture-wont-show-on-mobile-devices) and https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/560392384345729/

Comment: It was a Fb bug. I posted there and they fixed it. It is loading now. Donno why Zuckerberg let the API too many bugs always?

Comment: @dev-m can you please tell me how u fixed that?

Comment: read my previous comment again. It was a bug and reported here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/159445198061713 they fixed it.

Comment: It seems like the bug actually still is not fixed (or it can be another/similar bug). At least when I navigate to: https://graph.facebook.com/2290405257851751/picture?type=square for example. It shows a placeholder instead of the actual profile picture. I also reported this to facebook.