# Failed to load Facebook Graph API profile picture URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So this code was working fine for me before:

```
    FB.api("/me/picture?width=600&height=600", function(profile_picture)
    {
            user_me_picture = profile_picture.data.url;
    }
```

But after Facebook Dev update, the url parameter can't be loaded, it's because of new Facebook link on the Graph API:

```
{
  "data": {
    "height": 50,
    "is_silhouette": false,
    "url": "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1633647180278779&height=50&width=50&ext=1531277613&hash=AeTrVjn5tUK7zxEo",
    "width": 50
  }
}
```

Is there anyway I can fix my code with this new Facebook profile picture url?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You can't reach the URL? When i check it with my own API calls, the provided URL is accessible

Comment: @Igy The picture URL now works as an attached file which you are forced to download instead of displaying it

Comment: Works fine for me as well, just using it as an img src … It might be restricted under certain circumstances though, when Facebook might think its not a real browser trying to access this, or in private mode/with DNT, or stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably late, but this happened to me recently without a warning. Suddenly, my app stopped to load the user's profile picture.

After research a bit, i found out that, from now on, you need to call to the Facebook's API directly to download it.

Check this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513735/facebook-graph-user-picture-wont-show-on-mobile-devices) if you want to figure out of the "why of this" and how to fix it in depth, but in short, just add the Facebook's user id into the URI of the API like this:

[https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}/picture](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BuserId%7D/picture) where `userId` is the one returned by Facebook in the same API call.