# Use Facebook App-scoped Id for ProfilePictureView

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am implementing facebook's SDK for an android app. I have a `ProfilePictureView`, that requires, to be filled:

```
profilePictureView.setProfileId(id)
```

Yesterday, if I used the App-scoped Id of the profile (the one returned by Graph API) it worked: that's the only id I have, because apparently is against Facebook policy to get the "real" id.

But today, without any modification, it returns a null image. I am guessing they changed the backend, but if so, what is the purpose of `ProfilePictureView` if it requires an id that is against Facebook's policy to get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook graph user picture won't show on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513735/facebook-graph-user-picture-wont-show-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From 26 Mar 2018, all solutions related to manual link don't work anymore**

Use the code below

```
private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_PROFILE_IMAGE = "picture.type(large)";
    private static String FACEBOOK_FIELDS = "fields";

    private void getFacebookData() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                (object, response) -> {
                    updateAvatar(getImageUrl(response));
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString(FACEBOOK_FIELDS, FACEBOOK_FIELD_PROFILE_IMAGE);
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_PICTURE = "picture";
    private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_DATA = "data";
    private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_URL = "url";
    private String getImageUrl(GraphResponse response) {
        String url = null;
        try {
            url = response.getJSONObject()
                    .getJSONObject(FACEBOOK_FIELD_PICTURE)
                    .getJSONObject(FACEBOOK_FIELD_DATA)
                    .getString(FACEBOOK_FIELD_URL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works and i will use that solution, *but* now the old code works again. Maybe it was a temporary (but pretty long) backend issue that they just solved.

Comment: I notice only now that this solution is great for the user's profile pic, but what about a profile pic of another user, knowing his id?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself, since this question specifically asks for "getting a profile picture given the id", and the enlightening answer of Levon works only for the current user.

```
private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_PROFILE_IMAGE = "picture.type(large)";
private static String FACEBOOK_FIELDS = "fields";
private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_PICTURE = "picture";
private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_DATA = "data";
private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_URL = "url";

public static void getFacebookProfileUrl(String id, final Response<String> response) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/" + id,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graph) {
                    String imgUrl = getImageUrl(graph);
                    // imgUrl is the url of the profilepic of the user with given id. 
                    // Works both for "real" id and "app-scoped" id
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString(FACEBOOK_FIELDS, FACEBOOK_FIELD_PROFILE_IMAGE);
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}


private static String getImageUrl(GraphResponse response) {
    String url = null;
    try {
        url = response.getJSONObject()
                .getJSONObject(FACEBOOK_FIELD_PICTURE)
                .getJSONObject(FACEBOOK_FIELD_DATA)
                .getString(FACEBOOK_FIELD_URL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}
```