# android - Facebook image not loading in glide?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-glide

so this recently broke for me (not sure if it has to do with the Facebook scandal). But, now I cant load the image url I get back from the facebook login api into glide.

Here's my code.

```
    private void useFacebookButton()
    {
        facebookButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                playerID = profile.getId();
                firstName = profile.getFirstName();
                lastName = profile.getLastName();
                profileImage = profile.getProfilePictureUri(500,500).toString();
                Glide.with(getActivity().getBaseContext()).load(profileImage).centerCrop().into(someImageView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"facebook error :(");
                Log.d(TAG,error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

I get a url that comes back as `https://graph.facebook.com/<facebookID>/picture?height=500&width=500&migration_overrides=%7Boctober_2012%3Atrue%7D`

But glide cannot load that anymore. When I pop it into chrome it doesnt display the image, but forces a download now. And when i download its the correct image. This has just recently happened, it was working fine last week. Dont know if anyone has found a way to fix to this?!?

Comment: Maybe search stackoverflow because the question have been asked like 10 times today

Comment: @WizKid got any links to the most popular question on stack for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook graph user picture won't show on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513735/facebook-graph-user-picture-wont-show-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: oh thanks for the link ill follow that post, will leave my question here for now and will answer it myself once the answer is posted or just remove the question itself if that thread displays the solution

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/q/49516674/7542765