# Can't display Facebook user avatar with Facebook API and Graph

Tags: facebook, react-native

I'm working in a React-Native app, and I'm also allowing users to login using FBSDK.

There seems to be an issue at the moment when trying to get the profile picture URL.

There are also several reports of this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513624/i-cant-load-images-from-graph-facebook) but still, after a year doesn't seem to be solved.

Attempted many ways but none worked, it always tries to download the file, seems it's missing the mime-type according to what the browser says.

The URL it gives is the following:
`https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid={{myfbid}}&height=50&width=50&ext=1583348357&hash=AeTnFpMVwBXgFy_J`

Also tried using the graph url directly: `http://graph.facebook.com/{myid}/picture`

And if I add the `&redirect=false`, it returns a data object with the platform-lookaside URL.

Everything I try, it tries to download.

This is how I'm currently trying to get the image using Graph API.

```
new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(new GraphRequest(
                '/me',
                {
                    accessToken: fbToken,
                    parameters: {
                        fields: {
                            string: 'picture.type(large)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                graphRequestCallback
            )).start();
```

It works, but the URL is the same.

Any idea on how can I solve this? I might be missing something or the bug is still happening?

Comment: I have the issue. Have u solved this problem?

Comment: @kirimi there was a way from a github page i found but can't find it now, my friend ended up doing it on the backend in my case.

Comment: I have the same issue here. Does anyone know how to fix this? The avatar URLs sent by Facebook resolve to a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just change the graph url ([http://graph.facebook.com/{myid}/picture](http://graph.facebook.com/%7Bmyid%7D/picture)) from http to https, it should work for you. Not sure if that's a new fix in React Native or not, but that solved it for me.